# How to get table cell at specified index using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can get first or last table cell (e.g. for last row) using jQuery expression like below:

first cell: `$('#table tr:last td:first')` or last cell: `$('#table tr:last td:last')`

But, how can I get cell at *specific index*, for example index 2, using similar expression, i.e. something like `$('#table tr:last td:[2]')` ?

Regards.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes:

```
$('#table tr:last td:eq(1)')
```

that will give you the second `td` in the last row.

Comment: I'm assuming that if there are any `th` elements in the row that they will be skipped?

Comment: If one has `th` elements than the selector can be modified like this `$('#table tbody tr:last td:eq(1)')`. This assumes that the table has a `tbody` tag.

Answer (score 18):

It's very simple without jQuery, and will work faster and in more browsers:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var row = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
var cell = row.cells[2];
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

For example,

```
$('#table tr:last td:nth-child(2)')
```