# Check if text in cell is bold

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table in html. Some cells is bold and some is normal. How I can check if some cell is bold (for example i,j) and get text of that cell without tag .

Cells can have only text. If it bold - it should contain tag `<b>`. For example:

```
<tr>
<td>
Not bold text
</td>
<td>
<b> Bold text </b>
</td>
</tr>
```

PS I can't use class or id properties.
PSS It would be better without jQuery code, we are not using it for now

Comment: Please, post some revelant code (your html table) :)

Comment: We don't know how those cells are structured: can you provide us some examples?. Bold text can be rendered using standard HTML tags (like `<strong>` or `<b>`) or via stylesheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer how to get a reference to the cell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052862/34088

You can get the first child with `cell.firstChild`. This gives you a text node or a `<B>` node. You can check this with the `node.nodeType` which is 1 for DOM nodes or 3 for text nodes. Which gives:

```
function isBold(table, rowIdx, columnIdx) {
    var row = table.rows[rowIdx];
    var cell = row.cells[columnIdx];
    var node = cell.firstChild;
    if( node.nodeType === 3 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return node.nodeName === 'b' || node.nodeName === 'B';
}
```

Comment: What about having multiple tags inside the table cell? I think you will only detect the first tag. Something like `<tr><td><i>...</i><b>...</b></td></tr>` will return `false`.

Comment: OP just wanted the first tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the css font-weight property to detect if the text is in bold:

```
if ($("#td-id").css("font-weight") == "bold") {
  var boldText = $("#td-id").html();
  // Text is bold
}
```

If you don't use css, there must be a `<strong>`-tag (or `<b>`-tag) inside the table cell contents. You may extract the bold text with the following code:

```
var boldText = $("#td-id strong").html();
if (boldText != NULL) {
   // Text is bold
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on your HTML. If you use `<b>` or `<strong>` tags, then you can easily get text from those cells: `$('TD strong').text();`

If you make the text bold via CSS class, then you'd require the css class: `$('TD.classForBoldText').text();`

But if you've just made the text bold via generalizational css such as `TD { font-weight: bold; }` then you can't get the text of specific cells.