# How to change html on inside table cells using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I can get already the specied row by using this

```
var clicked_tr = null;
....
clicked_tr = $(this).parent().parent();
```

but I don't know how to get the column, so If I had

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Value1</td>
    <td>Value2</td>
    <td>Value3</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs update" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateData" data-id='<? echo $MissingConfNum['uniqueid'] ?>'><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  ....
</table>
```

how to change data on 2nd column by using this `clicked_tr` variable.

change `value2` into `nicenicenice`

Comment: `clicked_tr.find('td').eq(1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get table cell at specified index using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052571/how-to-get-table-cell-at-specified-index-using-jquery)

Comment: @Piwwoli yeah but don't know the syntax... cause on my mind about that code is `clicked_tr + "tr:last td:eq(1)".html("test");`

Comment: @StormSpirit Does my answer help?

Comment: @Piwwoli nope, cause I don't know the syntax, so adeneo answered it. cause that syntax before adeneo answered was I'm figuring something how to do that with already found tr (`clicked_tr`)

Comment: and this is what I've come up so far that `clicked_tr + "td:eq(1)".html("test");` instead `clicked_tr.find('td').eq(1).html('test')`

Comment: @StormSpirit Why are you not using the answer adeneo gave you though?

Comment: @Piwwoli im using it that's why I thanks him...

Answer (score 1):

Here:

https://jsfiddle.net/gnbvqLfz/1/

```
$('#sometable').on('click', 'tr', function()
{
    $clicked = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text('Hello!')
})
```

I gave the table an id and bound a click event to its rows. Now `$(this)` refers to the clicked row and `$(this).children('td')` would refer to each td of the clicked row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you are defining `clicked_tr`, but it would be better to use [delegated event binding](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and jQuery [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of two `.parent()` calls.

```
$(function(){
  $('table').on('click', '.update', function(){
    // value will contain the new value to add to the td
    var value = 'nicenicenice';
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html( value );
  });
});
```